# Combine the 'this' selector?

Tags: jquery, css

In jQuery I have selected a html class, and using `'this'` to reference it within the function. How can I select an `img` within that class?

The code under did not work:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">
    <img src="batman.png">
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".test").mouseover(function() { 
    console.log($(this img).attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: `$(this).find('img')` or `$('img', this)` It would be better if you elaborate more.

Comment: What class show the full code??

Comment: please share some more of your code to clarify what you are doing !

Comment: `this` isn't a CSS selector.

Comment: @Satpal: Write it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`$.fn.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method

```
$(this).find('img')
```

OR, use [`jQuery(selector ,context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context), internally it will be convert to `find()`

> context: A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

```
$('img', this)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, what exactly you are trying to achieve, but maybe you are trying to do this?

```
$(this).find('img')
```

See https://api.jquery.com/find/.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a selector.

`$('img', this)`